# Laravel Eloquent Relationship of tables through other tables in between

Tags: json, laravel, api, rest, eloquent

In Laravel, I have the following relationships between 4 models named LevelOne, LevelTwo, LevelThree and LevelFour:

```
//LevelOne Model
   public function levelTwo(){
       return $this->hasMany(LevelTwo::class);
   }
```

```
//LevelTwo Model
    public function levelOne(){
        return $this->belongsTo(LevelOne::class);
    }

    public function levelThree(){
        return $this->hasMany(LevelThree::class);
    }
```

```
//LevelThree Model
    public function levelTwo(){
        return $this->belongsTo(LevelTwo::class);
    }
    
    public function levelFour(){
        return $this->hasOne(LevelFour::class);
    }
```

```
//LevelFour Model
    public function levelThree(){
        return $this->belongsto(LevelThree::class);
    }
```

My Goal is to use a Controller, for this example les call it JoinController , and return a string like this

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Entry 1 at level one",
    "levelTwo": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "levelone_id": 1,
        "name": "Entry 1 on level two",
        "levelThree": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "leveltwo_id": 1,
            "name": "Entry x on level three",
            "levelFour": [
                {
                "id": 1,
                "levelthree_id": 1,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                },
                {
                "id": 2,
                "levelthree_id": 1,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                }
            ]
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "leveltwo_id": 1,
            "name": "Entry x on level three",
            "levelFour": [
                {
                "id": 3,
                "levelthree_id": 2,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                },
                {
                "id": 4,
                "levelthree_id": 2,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "levelone_id": 1,
        "name": "Entry 2 on level two",
        "levelThree": [
            {
            "id": 3,
            "leveltwo_id": 2,
            "name": "Entry x on level three",
            "levelFour": [
                {
                "id": 5,
                "levelthree_id": 3,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                },
                {
                "id": 6,
                "levelthree_id": 3,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                }
            ]
            },
            {
            "id": 4,
            "leveltwo_id": 2,
            "name": "Entry x on level three",
            "levelFour": [
                {
                "id": 7,
                "levelthree_id": 4,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                },
                {
                "id": 8,
                "levelthree_id": 4,
                "name": "Entry x on level four"
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    //.... same as previous, n times
}]
```

So far, from JoinController I am able to successfully return "one level down" of information:

```
public function getAllLevels(){
  return LevelOne::with('levelTwo')->get();
}
```

However it fails when I try to go another level down, like this:

```
public function getAllLevels(){
  return LevelOne::with('levelTwo')->with('levelThree')->get();
}
```

The error is: *Call to undefined relationship [levelThree] on model [App\Models\LevelOne].*

However, if I return the following:

```
return LevelTwo::with('levelOne')->with('levelThree')->get();
```

This works with one relationship "up" and one relationship "down", BUT if I add LevelFour it will not work.
(Yes, I am importing the Models correctly at the top of the controller: use \App\Models\LevelOne; use \App\Models\LevelTwo; ... etc)

In plain SQL I would just write a query joining the foreign keys for the desired result. In Eloquent I am unsure how to make a LevelOne Model have a relationship with LevelFour when they are not connected through any ID but through other Model Tables in Between, like a cascade join. Please point me in the right direction.

Note: It is very important for me to return a string (json) like the one I showed before, I need to return all values of LevelOne, show all the rows from its relationship at LevelTwo and so forth and so on "n" times (in my case, 4 times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to probably change the relation in LevelThree

```php
//LevelThree Model
    public function levelTwo(){
        return $this->belongsTo(LevelTwo::class);
    }
    
    public function levelFour(){
        return $this->hasOne(LevelFour::class);
    }
```

Then you can form a query like

```php
public function getAllLevels()
{
    return LevelOne::with('levelTwo.levelThree.levelFour')->get();
}
```

Comment: My original code had the correct relationship like you suggested to change LevelThree, I wrote it wrong here. I have edited the question with the correct code.

The query using with('levelTwo.levelThree.levelFour') worked, so simple, yet I was unable to find this in the documentation. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things you could give a look.
First of all, for relations between not 2 but 3 levels, try to look for hasManyThrough. This way you could get from levelOne to levelThree directly, without invoking levelTwo at all. Same way up, however then you might need to try

As you said
The error is: Call to undefined relationship [levelThree] on model [App\Models\LevelOne].

This is because when calling with() you are still doing that to LevelOne, not LevelTwo. LevelOne::with('levelTwo') does not return you LevelTwo, but a LevelOne with the instance/instances of LevelTwo under that name, so you can access it $levelOne->levelTwo. If you want to call 'withs' to go through the returned instances, you need to write a comma and the name of the next relation, just like this.

```
LevelOne::with('levelTwo.levelThree.levelFour')->get();
```